# Python Eve - POST payload containing a list

Tags: python, eve

I am having trouble with the `list` type in my schemas. Whenever I try to POST, I get a 422 response stating 'must be of list type'. Below is a simple example that produces this problem.

```
from eve import Eve

people = {
    'schema': {
        'tests': {
            'type': 'list',
            'schema': {
                'type': 'string'
            },
            'required': True,
        }
    },
    'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST'],
}

settings = {
    'DOMAIN': {
        'people': people
    }
}
app = Eve(settings=settings)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Then when you POST to the people endpoint with the following:

```
import requests

url = "http://localhost:5000/people"

person = {
    "tests": ['a', 'b'],
}

r = requests.post(url, data=person)
print(r.json())
```

You get the 422 response. When I debug this, it looks like the Eve application has received the `tests` parameter as just a string, `'a'`, rather than the whole list. From what I can see in the Eve tests on GitHub, this seems to be the right way to make the request, so I can only assume I'm making a mistake in setting up the resource/schema?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print `request.POST`, you would see `UnicodeMultiDict([('tests', u'a'), ('tests', u'b')])`. Fix to this would be to use `json object` for your `post`.

```
person = json.dumps({
    "tests": ['a', 'b'],
})

r = requests.post(url, json=person)
print(r.json())
```

Or in your case, you will have to somehow tweak your POST request at API end to get a list as:- 
`request.POST.getall('tests')` and then proceed.

Please check [using json in POST request](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests). Also while using `json`, json.dumps may not be required, the dictionary will be `jsonified` automatically.

Comment: Ah, that works, thanks. I didn't realise there was a `json`argument in requests. I had already tried `data=json.dumps(payload)`, which gives a 400 error. Now looking at the [requests docs](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) I thought they would be equivalent.

Comment: Probably I should add this link to the answer.

Comment: I found that the reason `json=person` works where `data=json.dumps(person)` doesn't is because the json keyword argument also changes the request header to `application/json`, where the manual dump doesn't.

Comment: @AndrewWalker Ok. Thanks. I didn't knew this.